# Is orthogonality of column vectors preserved after right-multiplication by unitary matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$\mathbf V$ is an $n \times (n-1)$ matrix with mutually orthogonal columns.
$\mathbf Q$ is a unitary matrix of size $(n-1) \times (n-1)$. Is there a concise algebraic proof that the columns of $\mathbf {VQ}$ are mutually orthogonal?

In a [proof of the Spectral Theorem](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/thm_sed.html), it is claimed that the columns of $\mathbf {VQ}$ are orthogonal by construction. I would like to find a way to verify that this is generally true.

Comment: The columns of $V$ are mutually orthogonal $\iff V^*V=I$ is the identity matrix. You can then check that if $V^*V=I$ (the columns of $V$ are orthogonal) and $Q^*=Q^{-1}$ ($Q$ is unitary) then $$(VQ)^*(VQ)=Q^*V^*VQ=Q^{-1}IQ=I,$$ i.e. the columns of $VQ$ are orthogonal.

Comment: Good answer. That is exactly what I was looking for, ie. using class properties to reach the conclusion.

Comment: @arctictern You're assuming that the columns of $\mathrm V$ are not merely orthogonal, but also orthonormal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Q(i)$ be the $i$-th column of $Q$. Think of the product $VQ$ as
$$R = VQ = \begin{bmatrix} VQ(1) & VQ(2) &VQ(3) &\cdots&VQ(n) \end{bmatrix}$$.

We want to show that $\langle R(i), R(j) \rangle = 0,\forall i \neq j$, 
\begin{align*}
&\langle R(i), R(j) \rangle\\
=&Q(i)^TV^T V Q(j) \\
=&Q(i)^TIQ(j)\\
=&Q(i)^TQ(j) \\
=& 0
\end{align*}
Since the columns of $V$ are mutually orthogonal (actually they need to be mutually orthonormal),  $V^TV = I \in R^{n \times n}$. $Q$ is an unitary matrix, therefore its columns are also mutually orthogonal.

Comment: How come "mutually orthogonal" implies "orthonormal"?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean imply here. I wanted to say that the columns of $V$ should really be orthonormal, which is what they are defined as in the Spectral Theorem link.

Answer (score -1):

A unitary matrix preserves the scalar product, hence preserves the orthogonality of two vectors.

Comment: I am concerned with orthogonality of the column vectors of $\mathbf V$, which are $\in \Bbb R ^n$. Right-multiplication by $\mathbf Q$ is a transformation that acts on row-vectors in $\Bbb R ^{n-1}$. It is not obvious to me that if the scalar product of the row-vectors of $\mathbf V$ is preserved therefore the scalar product of the column-vectors of $\mathbf V$ is also preserved.

Comment: I see.  I think the main challenges are to (1) describe what subspace of ${\bf R}^n$ the operator ${\bf Q}$ acts on, and (2) to use the dual basis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_basis to relate what you started thinking of as the row vectors and column vectors of a matrix.

I know this is incomplete, and the problem is complicated, but this is the usual confusion that results when linear algebra is taught in terms of matrices and "row-" and "column-" vectors: the coordinates distract from the geometry, which is the main content.  That's why the only book I would recommend is Halmos's.

Comment: I think that the "Not seeing the forest for the trees" type of scenario does apply to me, at least some of the time. I will look at the Dual Basis stuff that you linked to and I'll try to incorporate it into my thinking.

Comment: It applies not to you, but to every course where operations on matrices and coordinate vectors are called "linear algebra".  Coordinate manipulations obscure "the forest," which is the geometry (i.e., a coordinate-free theory!) of linear spaces.  I kept having exactly the same experience until I got tired of it and worked through Halmos's book.  Never had a problem again.